# Making handles around a path fit the size of that path

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've just been using some UI templates and in some cases, the 'bounding box' for transformations is huge compared to the actual object in it.  For example, I have a little 'back arrow' shape probably 40px wide, but the transformation box is more than 1000 wide and high.  How do I 'clip' or crop it (for want of a better term).  It may be called fitting the frame to the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bounding box is sized to fit the layer contents and any associated layer mask. You can't "clip" the bounding box. If you want a smaller bounding box, you need to remove stray pixels from the layer and possibly apply any associated layer mask.